# Pass unknown number of arguments to HTML onclick event attribute

Tags: javascript, html

The following HTML contains `inputs` in which the user writes his quiz answers. Some HTML pages will contain more (up to 20) `inputs`. I am looking for a way to pass in **all** `input.values` stored in `inputArray`.

```
   <p>Question 1</p>
    <input type="text" class="answer-input"><br>
    <p>Question 2</p>
    <input type="text" class="answer-input"><br>
    <p>Question 3</p>
    <input type="text" class="answer-input"><br>  
<script>
    const inputArray = document.querySelectorAll(".answer-input");
</script>
```

Right now, I am passing in every `input.value` manually, depending on the number of existing input fields, to be validated by the `validateResult()` function.
In short, I am trying to find a dynamic solution for:

```
  <button type="button" onclick="quiz1.validateResult(
        inputArray[0].value,
        inputArray[1].value,
        inputArray[2].value
        );">Check Results</button>
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: use the `forEach()` collection method or the `for {}` cycle.

Comment: I was reading your sentence and realized how weird my question is. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.